# Getting values for items in a list

Tags: where-in

I have a list of items based on ItemDescription.

I'm trying to find their ItemID based on the ItemDescription from my Item table.

I'm sure it's not difficult, but I can't seem to find a basic query for this.

Also, apologies for poor formatting, I'm REALLY new to programming.

I think I need a *where-in* clause.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the data look like follows,

```
ItemID | ItemDescription
------------------------
1      | Description1  
2      | Description2  
3      | Description3  
4      | Description1
```

Use that query:

```
SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE ItemDescription='Description1';
```

The answer for the SQL query is

```
ItemID
------
1 
4
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.
What if your 'something' is a large list

Comment: Do you mean an array? If it's that, use $array = array("el1","el2"); for($i=0;$i<maxnumber;$i++){mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE ItemDescription='".$array[$i]."'");}

Comment: I don't know what an array is exactly, so I don't know.

A simple example is if I'm trying to get the ISBN of say 80 books, but I only have the book titles.

Comment: Then you have to use the query I wrote before.If you want to use it into a php code, you'll have to write something like this.<?php $con = mysqli_connect("","","",""); while($select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE ItemDescription='something'"))){echo $ItemID;} ?>